# Arduino esp8266 device gets Bad Request error from apache server while making request from

Tags: apache, http-headers, webserver, arduino-esp8266

I am sending post request from my arduino device to my hosted server it gives me 400 Bad request error.
Same code runs well in my localhost but not working on Hosted server.
My arduino code if give below.

```
    void callApi(String ID,String path,int comm,String message,int isResponseNeeded) {    
                  String serverPath="www.xyz.com";
                  String data = "{" ;
                  data = data + "\"id\": \""+ID+"\"," ;
                  data = data + "\"version\": \""+VERSION+"\"," ;
                  data = data + "\"command\": \""+comm+"\"," ; 
                  data = data + "\"message\": \""+message+"\"" ;
                  data = data + "}" ;
                  Serial.print("Send data...on=>");
                  Serial.println(path);
                  if (wifiClient.connect(serverPath,80)) {
                    Serial.println(data);
                    wifiClient.println("POST /abc/xyz HTTP/1.1");  
                    wifiClient.println("Content-Type: application/json");
                    wifiClient.print("Host: ");
                    wifiClient.println(serverPath);
                    wifiClient.print("Content-Length: ");
                    wifiClient.println(data.length());
                    wifiClient.print("\n");
                    wifiClient.print(data);
                    wifiClient.print("\n");
                    Serial.println("Data sent...Reading response..");
                    if(isResponseNeeded>0){
                       unsigned long timeout = millis();
                       while (wifiClient.available() == 0) {
                         if (millis() - timeout > 10000) {
                          Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
                          break;
                         }
                      }     
                    String response;
                      while(wifiClient.available()){
                        String line = wifiClient.readStringUntil('\n');
                        response=line;     
                        Serial.println(response);   
                      }
                      Serial.println(response.length()); 

                }
```

## out put of this code.

{"id": "_60_1_94_f_a9_3c_","version": "1.10","command": "0","message": ""}

Data sent...Reading response..

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Date: Sat, 20 May 2017 05:13:41 GMT

Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Content-Length: 324

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at ubuntu-512mb-nyc2-01.localdomain Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

===========================================================
And one one more thing i have observed that. it runs GET request fine. only it cause issue while making POST request on my hosted server.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that API service requires POST content and body to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoded.

[application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data/4073451#4073451)